# Regex for not comma and space before string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a specific word, but not if the string ' ,' is precededing it. I tried

```
((?!\,\s))(word)
```

However, thats not working. I was expecting it to match the word 'word'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need a lookbehind not lookahead. What is regex flavor?

Comment: Im doing it in xslt, if that helps.

Comment: Your posted text is `' ,'` That would be a space then comma.

Comment: The fastest way is to do it with the lookbehind after the word. `\bword\b(?<!,\sword)` This is fastest because it finds the _word_ first then checks the assertion, and can be 5-20 times faster than the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have coded a negative look *ahead*. Try a negative look *behind*:

```
(?<!,\s)word
```

Also note that you don't need most of the brackets you coded.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the answer is a lookbehind assertion.
The difference is where to put it.

*Any* regex that starts with an assertion is going to be dog slow.
The reason is that assertions can't be optimized to the point of insertion.

For that reason, it may look big, but it makes a difference in performance
from 5 to 20 times.

Sample

```
word asdfasdf  afsdbbasbfasfb 
adbbadfb, afdsbafbdsasfb adb, , , ,
word, word word, word
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   (?<!,\s)word
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.70 s,   703.28 ms,   703277 µs


Regex2:   word(?<!,\sword)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.17 s,   170.21 ms,   170207 µs
```